# Injecting PHP generated HTML into Angular 7 App Component

Tags: php, angular

**Overview**
I have created a single page Angular 7 app which serves as the backend of a website. I would like to upgrade to Angular 7 from AngularJS for the frontend website, but I have concerns about SEO. At the end of the day, I like the component structure of Angular 2+ and typescript as opposed to AngularJs. I would also like to avoid Angular Universal at this time due to time constraints.

**Problem**
As it is today, the front end website generates the HTML on the server side and the AngularJS app bootstraps using the ng-app attribute on the body element. This works great for SEO since all the html is already served/available. When trying to use Angular 2+, the html has to be part of the app component template and I have yet to figure out how I can bind the app component to the generated html from the server. I'm okay with child components using client-side templates, but I'd like to get the majority of the website generated on the server side and then have a library of cool components that I can simply inject into the html generated by the server.

What I'd like to be able to do:

```html
<!-- All the following HTML is generated on the server side (PHP)-->
<body>
  <app-root>
   <!-- how to tell the app component to use this html instead of whatever is compiled in Angular? -->
    <div id="App Root Component">
      <div>Some html</div>
      <component-a tag="does some cool stuff"></component-a><!-- Angular now behaves as normal here -->
      <div>Some other html</div>
      <component-b tag="does other cool stuff"></component-b><!-- Angular now behaves as normal here -->
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

This doesn't work because the AppComponent will overwrite all content within  with its own template.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',/*The html in here will overwrite all contents within <app-root>, even if it's empty, or if this statement is omitted*/
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app-www';
}
```

Perhaps I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole here, but it seems to me that it would be pretty cool to have most of the static html generated on the server side while having the flexibility to use the features of Angular 2+ for various interactive components.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you concerned about SEO. Angular 2+ is client side scripting framework that will generate HTML on the user's browser. When you see source code then it won't display rendered HTML.

Google has already started crawling JS framework based website. But some how its not at it best.

You solution to server website from server side could be using [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal). This will server HTML to browser rather rendering at user's browser.

If you are not comfortable with that you can purchase https://prerender.io/ that will store your static pages(crawled by them) on their server and when bot requesting page that time serving those static pages.

I hope this answers your problem.